# Is it possible to write typed, but generic, functional components to be used by non-React runtimes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

We're wanting to distribute components with the intention that they may be consumed by any compatible runtime. These components are just functions written in JSX, and transpiled to a generic factory function, `h`. The output should therefore (for the most part) be compatible with React, Preact, Inferno, Hyperapp, vhtml, etc. For example, here is a simple `<Title />` component:

```
import { h } from 'runtime';

const Title = ({ title, url }) => (
    <div className="component-heading">
        <a href={url} className="component-heading-link">
            {title}
        </a>
    </div>
);

export default Title;
```

We'd like to decorate our components with types, primarily so that the consumer gets help when passing properties along to them. If we borrow the React typings it could look like this:

```
import { SFC } from 'react';
import { h } from 'runtime';

export interface Props { … }

const Title: SFC<Props> = ({ title, url, premium }) => (
    <div className="component-heading">
        <a href={url} className="component-heading-link">
            {title}
        </a>
    </div>
);

export default Title;
```

This is very nice if the consumer is using TypeScript and React, but if they are using Preact or any other compatible runtime the types will clash.

Is it therefore possible to write functional components that are generic enough to be used by non-React runtimes?

Comment: I think you should distribute pure JS code and TypeScript definition files (those `.d.ts`). This is e.g. how Angular is distributed (take a look e.g. here: https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/).